# How to create a VM with multiple NIC's in Azure ARM

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-resource-manager

Has anyone been able to create a VM with multiple private IP's in ARM? I've tried setting different VM sizes but still cannot find out how to attach multiple NIC's to 1 VM. I'm trying to do this in the new ARM mode but cannot find a way to do so.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can only add multiple network interface resources to a VM using PowerShell or JSON, and it can only be done during VM creation.

Comment: Not sure what you mean about using JSON (maybe referring to an ARM template?) but... PowerShell sits atop the ARM API, as does the CLI.

Answer (score 0):

The nics have to have been created before hand and you have to choose a vm which supports multiple NICs. Also, Create a virtual network with one subnet must have been created before hand as well.

Using Azure Cli 2.0

- azure login
- azure config mode arm
- azure vm create -g myresourcegroup -n myVMname -l AzureLocation -y {windows|linux} -N myNic1, myNic2 -Q Win2012R2Datacenter  -u myUserName -p myPassword -z ‘AzureVM Size’   -v

Wait 5 minutes
and you are done